# Thunderbird stop opening in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: thunderbird, 17.10

this morning with no reason I cannot be able anymore to open Thunderbird in Ubuntu 17.10.

I purge the application and I install Thunderbird again, some problem.

If I log in in Gnome Desktop, Thunderbird work correctly.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem that seems like the problem to open Synaptic in Ubuntu 17.10

Thanks

Bye

Luca

Comment: This is caused by Wayland. It is a recognised bug. Wayland does not give permissions to open apps like synaptic package manager. Have you tried logging into Xorg session?

Comment: Yes in Xorg session It works

Comment: @AlanJameson I don't think so. Thunderbird doesn't require `sudo` or `gksudo` to run. Affected apps are Synaptic package manager, Gparted etc.

Comment: No the problem with synaptic is the same with thunderbird

Comment: @LucaTansini How? Are you launching Thunderbird with `sudo`?! :O That's a horrible idea!

Comment: No just click on the icon

Comment: I Just tested thunderbird on Ubuntu 17.10. Runs fine from my side.

Comment: Good for you, I have to use Ubuntu with Xorg

Comment: I checked today a lot of Graphic Application that do not work in Ubuntu 17.10 with Wayland.

Comment: Wayland is not a new feature, IS A BIG BUG!!!

Comment: As soon as I said that Wayland is a BUG, I didn't received anymore comments or answers ?!